# Export or save file on download to dropbox or google drive using Magento2 programmatically

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5, google-api, download

I want add new functionality on download product by adding download file to google drive or dropbox in magento2 programmatically either using extension or api.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707891/google-drive-php-api-simple-file-upload/25715084#25715084 ?

Comment: Yes i checked but not working as it is done using composer package.

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php